# place PHP echo text in specific place in html

Tags: php, html, css

I'm using html and PHP to read text from file and echo it in the page - it's sort of a list.
the issue is that I don't want to put it at the top of the page, as PHP echo by default, but to put it in specific place - after on div and before another.

the php snippet:

```
$lines = file('http://localhost/repositories.txt');
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
echo  "<a onclick='javascript:(document.folderForm.folderLocation.value=".htmlspecialchars(json_encode($line)) .");' href='#'>".htmlspecialchars($line) . "</a><br />";
```

thanks.

Comment: You can place the php code with php opening and closing tag wherever you wish; just place the code after the div you're considering.

Answer (score 1):

You can save your FOREACH loop for the div that you want it to be placed in your HTML

```
<?php
$lines = file('http://localhost/repositories.txt');
?>
<html>
<div>Some other text on my page</div>
<div><?php foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
echo  "<a onclick='javascript:(document.folderForm.folderLocation.value=".htmlspecialchars(json_encode($line)) .");' href='#'>".htmlspecialchars($line) . "</a><br />"; ?></div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
<?php
$lines = file('http://localhost/repositories.txt');
$list=""; //declare empty varialbe

foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
$list .=  "<a onclick='javascript:(document.folderForm.folderLocation.value=".htmlspecialchars(json_encode($line)) .");' href='#'>".htmlspecialchars($line) . "</a><br />";
/* .= cause the append to the variable */
}
?>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta ....... />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Some div</div>
    <div><?php echo $list; ?></div>
    <div>Some div</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

put all your html junk here then when you ready add this                                                                                                                 `<?`$lines = file('http://localhost/repositories.txt');
      foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line)    echo"".htmlspecialchars($line) . "
";`?>`               The open and close php marks lets you put it exactly where you want